# Create RSA-SHA256 sign with PEM key

Tags: node.js, typescript, cryptography, sign

I've been creating a gateway for a legacy service, this legacy service needs a signature as a body parameter of a PUT request, in order to create this sign I need to follow the following steps:

1. Create a *hash* with certain text as data, this *hash* needs to be *SHA256*.
2. Encrypt the result of the *hash* using *RSA* with a PEM key
3. Encode the result of the *RSA* to Base64

Following the previous steps I create the following code

```
export class Signature {
  // class body
  public static sign(text: string){
    const key = readFileSync('key.pem')
    const passphrase = '12345678'
    const createdSign = createSign('RSA-SHA256')
    createdSign.write(text)
    createdSign.end()
    return createdSign.sign({ key, passphrase }).toString('base64')
  } 
}
```

But I'm not sure if this the correct implementation, taking into consideration the previous steps, and the existence of the *hash* API in NodeJS.

If someone could tell me if I'm correctly implementing this algorithm.

Comment: I can't find any (at least obvious) bug, which can also be concluded from a comparison with the code from the documentation (e.g. [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_sign) and [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createsign_algorithm_options)). Independent of this, the generated signature can also be proofed by performing the verification. The latter can be done with NodeJS or in another way, e.g. [here](https://8gwifi.org/rsasignverifyfunctions.jsp) with the option SHA256withRSA.  Is there a concrete issue or is there a reason why you suspect a problem?

Comment: Doesn't look like `crypto.sign(algorithm, data, key)` to me, but maybe I'm looking at the wrong API description? Anyway, the proof of signature generation lies in the verification. If the verification succeeds then the signature is correct with about 100% certainty.